# How do I join several objects into one?

Tags: modeling, objects

I'm creating side skirts for a truck and I am duplicating the frames I want. The problem is it's making the duplicated object into another object. How do I put it into the same one?

[image: how do I make one file for each model]

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Do you want to make those into one object? (`Ctrl+J`)

Comment: I want to make each model into only one layer for each of them

Comment: for example I have model6.000 and model6.10 I want to make it so the are both within model6.10 only

Comment: Try selecting them both (selecting `model6.10` last) and pressing `Ctrl+J`

Comment: it only lets me select one object

Comment: Are you in edit mode? Try switching to *object mode* (press `Tab`)

Comment: yeah im in object mode

Comment: And you are selecting with `Shift+RMB`?

Comment: no I wasn't mate im selecting with going to the 6.000 then right click select then 6.10 right click select and doing ctrl+j

Comment: So does using `Shift+RMB` work?

Comment: yes thank you very much mate your help has been very usefull cheers buddy

Comment: yeah buddy its not working now

Comment: What's not working? (the selection? or joining?)

Comment: both I do the selecting but im having to use the LMB

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.. Could you clarify?

Comment: hey man I get the selecting bit right as one outlines as orange but the ctrl+j doesn't work

Comment: That's odd.. Are there any error messages? (look at the top bar next to the blender logo right after it fails)

Comment: nah no error is showing up fella

Comment: I got it to work on one but its not working on another one

Comment: Are you sure the objects you are trying to join are all the same [type](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects#Types_of_Objects)? (e.g. mesh, curve, etc.)

Comment: yeah as they have been duplicated

Comment: when I click on the + next to the model the meshmodel has a different code

Comment: @user2004 I feel that you were trying to do everything that ganfalf3 said within the Outliner window. When hitting Ctrl J, make sure the mouse is over the 3D View area, or by the 3D View header menu "Object" > "Join".

Comment: yes that's right my friend haha

Comment: thanks guys you have given me some useful tips and how to do this I found the problem was I did it in the outliner column thank you

Comment: The mesh data (the entry with the inverted triangle) is stored separately from the object. When you merge objects, the mesh data from one data block is merged into the active objects mesh data block. The old datablock will still be around until you reload the blend file, which is why it has a different name. You don't need to worry about this, if the meshes display with with a yellow outline when selected, they are joined.

Comment: thank you thee only problem im having now is when I do this it inverts the object so it becomes invisible

Comment: Try recalculating the normals (Enter edit mode (`Tab`), select all (`A`), and recalculate normals by pressing `Ctrl+N`)

Comment: how do I give you two reputation or something like that

Comment: sorry I tried and said it wasn't available due to only 1 other member

Comment: @iKlsR I tried, but apparently you need more than 1 rep to chat. user2004 If my answer has answered your question, you can accept it by clicking the check mark. Feel free to [take the tour](http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour) for more info.

Comment: @gandalf3 If someone doesn't have the privilege, ping a mod or make a room and give them access privilege there.

Comment: I have edited your question to use terminology which I think you meant. Please rollback if my edits are incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

You can join *[objects](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects)* by [selecting them](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects/Selecting) (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd>) and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> in the *3D view* while on Object mode.

The selected object(s) will be joined to the *[active object](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects/Selecting#Selections_and_the_Active_Object).*

The active object the one with the yellow outline, usually the last object selected.

[image]

Comment: Note that this is done in **Object Mode**

Answer (score 0):

you can move an object to another layer by: object mode + m + select the intended layer

reference: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Putting_Hat_on_Person

Comment: @user2004 seems to mean objects, not layers. If I understood their question correctly, they want to join the objects, nothing to do with layers.