# UV unwrap doesn't show faces in UV image editor

Tags: interface, uv

I am following [this tutorial](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/UV_Map_Basics), however for some reason the mesh isn't appearing in the UV image editor.

According to the tutorial, it should look like this:
[image]

However in my blender, it looks like this:
[image]

Obviously I tried to show the UV texture coordinates by pressing U and selecting "Unwrap".

I have tried looking at this [Blender StackExchange question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7889/unwrapped-not-appearing-in-uv-editor), however the answer there says "only selected faces will be unwrapped", and I think I have them all unwrapped.

Comment: Try selecting all the faces in the object by pressing "A", at the top it should say `Faces: 432/432` after doing that instead of what it is currently saying `Faces: 0/432` this means you have no faces selected and as you said only selected faces show up in the UV image editor

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/110499/uv-map-will-not-show-on-uv-editor there I describe my solution when ripping textures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several objects selected and then you have gone into edit mode on one object, the active one. This is evident by the fact that the entire ship appears to be selected (from the orange outline) yet it's vertex data is not shown. This may be misleading you if you expect the entire ship to show in the UV editor.

Only the selected faces of the active object will show in the UV editor, in your screen shot you only have 2 vertices selected, which is why no UV faces of the object are shown. Press <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to de-select the two vertices and then select all of the vertices in the active object, then unwrap and then they will show spread out in the UV editor.

You will need to repeat this for each object unless you wish to join them together into one.

Comment: How do I join them together into one?

Comment: [Join them as shown here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5871/935)