# UV map will not show on UV editor

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I have some problems with the UV editor.

After using the Ninjaripper to implement some .rip files into Blender and adding the converted .dds files it messes with me. I aplyed a new material and used the showen Nodes to use also some transparency (what is important for that little figure). After that I want to create one singe image were all materials are on. And there is my problem. As you can see when I try to get the UV it does not show but the texture is perfectly aplyed to the mesh! 
I also not hide anything. In picture 3 you can see that the baseplate I designed after implement that is also perfect and show the UV as it should be. 
when I use the Unwrap command that it totally messes up the aplyed texture so that I never could get the picture back were it should be.

So my question: How can I show the "actual" used UV or how can I fix that problem... Invested several hours to read forums but all say I should unwrap and replace textures what is nearly impossible. 
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload images so that they appear as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: Make sure Uv editor > footer > UV Local View is not enabled. Make sure all UV islands are not somewhere away from the center of UV editor (try pressing A 1 or 2 times to select all and press Numpad period). If something esle is going on share your file with https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thats what I done first, tryed to catch UV with 2x a and after that did not worked I zoomed out untill picture was only 1 pixel wide. Still no UV found. Local view is and was turned off.  So sadly no solution jet.

Comment: Even weirder is that when I load the same blend I used to upload here it replace all textures with a pink material?!?! While showing me the right material preview. No idea why. Does Blener not know how to interpret his own materials? Would be nice if somone can help me with the problem, I try not to get this only figure I want do some more and understand why and what happend here, but reached the limits of my skill at the moment.

Comment: OK, after 6 Days intensive searching I found the solution no one could help me... maybe it helps others now.

Comment: So to show your UV you activate the edit mode with TAB and than go to the UV editor and pus a twice to fetch the uv mesh. Than you can open with "n" the bar were you cn see the parameter of your UV and enter there under UV Vertex a usefull location like 0/0. In my case it was at -1256/2800, that was also the reason why I never could find it when zooming out, because it was too small and to far away.

Comment: The UV when you import with a ripper programm is placed sooooo far out that you can not see it. A friend described it to me that it than scale up untill it fits into the texture.