# Blender basic , selecting and merge objects

Tags: uv

I am novice, I saw several post saying that for merge you need to select all ( pressing A) and then Control+J

but in my case it doesnt work (I think that is because are separated objets) I added a screenshot with better explanation

[image]

I have downloaded learn to paint it,I need to merge both objects to UV unwrap

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5873/15543  Join objects in object mode. Your screenshot is in edit mode where  A selects all verts.

Comment: That was the fail! thank you very much ! you can post the answer so I can accept it for futures newbie like me!

Comment: Hello, I am NoviceInDisguise ;)