# Want to join objects for unity

Tags: unity, parent, makehuman

I am making a 3d Tennis game in Unity. I have made human objects in Makehuman and successfully imported them in blender.

I want the human object in blender to hold the tennis recket object imported from another file so that when I animate in unity the tennis racket moves when the hand of the tennis player moves.

How can I achieve that in blender.

Comment: use ctrl + j to combine multiple selected objects into one , see [How do I join several objects into one](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5873/2816)

Comment: if you want the two objects to move together but stay separate , see [How do I “parent” objects](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/26108/2816)